# How to extract all text from html excluding css and javascript with lxml in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

How can I extract all text from a html excluding any css and javascript?

I am trying the following code:

```
r = requests.get(website)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
html_text = tree.xpath('//text()')
```

But it also retrieves all css and javascript content from the website

Comment: So you want to exclude everything in `<script>` and `<style>` tags?

Comment: @mzjn Yes, it is right. I want to exclude everything from `<script>` and `<style>` extracting only all the readable text from the html

Comment: How do you define the "readable text" in terms that can be translated into a program in your case? Everything which is not in `<script>` or `<style>`?

Comment: All text that is not in `<script>` and `<style>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`drop_tree()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html#drop_tree) method to remove elements that you are not interested in.

```
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)

unwanted = tree.xpath('//script|//style')
for u in unwanted:
    u.drop_tree()

html_text = tree.xpath('//text()')
```